# The Remainder of $\frac{2000!}{5^{397}}$ (Just Checking my theory)

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

## The remainder of $\frac{2000!}{5^{397}}$

This is a question from my homework.
The remainder of $\frac{2000!}{5^{397}}$

My answer is there is no remainder.
Solution: There are 400 numbers that can be divisible by 5 between 2000 and 1.
So all three hundred and ninety seven 5's will be used up to cancel 397 numbers out of those 400 numbers.
Therefore, there is no remainder.
For example, consider $\frac{10!}{2^{5}}$
There are 5 numbers that can be divisible by 2 between 10 and 1.
$\frac{10!}{2^{5}}=\frac{10\times9\times8\times7\times6\times5\times4\times3\times2\times1}{2\times2\times2\times2\times2}$
Then all you left with
${5\times9\times4\times7\times3\times5\times2\times3\times1\times1}$
So is my explanation right?

Comment: Seems like a fine explanation.

Comment: Sounds good to me

Comment: Your explanation is great, and in fact the answer would be the same even for much higher exponents.  5 is divisible by 2000/5 = 400 of the numbers 1,2, ..., 2000, 25 is divisible 2000/25=80 times, 125, 16 times and 625 3 times.  Therefore even $5^{499}$ divides 2000!.

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation works here. However it doesn't work all the time. For instance, consider $$5^{401} \backslash 2000!$$ which is true, but your method fails here.

In such questions, the best method is to find the exponent of prime $p(=5)$ in $n$ factorial $(=2000!)$
$$\begin{aligned}
 &= \left\lfloor \frac{2000}{5} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{2000}{5^2} \right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{2000}{5^3} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{2000}{5^4} \right\rfloor \\
 &= 400 + 80 + 16 + 3 \\
 &= 499
\end{aligned}
$$

Here we see that $$5^x \backslash 2000!$$ holds true upto $x = 499$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.

In the sequence of the factors of $2000!$, every fifth factor is a multiple of $5$, and no other.

These factors are

$$5,10,15,\cdots 2000$$ and when divided by $5$,

$$1,2,3,\cdots 400,$$ which, by the way, are the factors of $400!$

To know the total number of fives in $2000!$, you can iterate $2000\to400\to80\to16\to3$ and get

$$400+80+16+3.$$